How to make package project to xcframework
This is my Package.swift:
// swift-tools-version: 5.8
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "ios-client-sdk",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v13)
    ],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "ios-client-sdk",
            targets: ["ios-client-sdk"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift.git", from: "1.16.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/jwt-kit.git", from: "4.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift.git", from: "1.8.3"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA", from: "1.8.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/airsidemobile/JOSESwift", from: "3.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/Kitura/Swift-JWT.git", from: "4.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git", from: "0.15.3")
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "ios-client-sdk",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "GRPC", package: "grpc-swift"),
                .product(name: "JWTKit", package: "jwt-kit"),
                .product(name: "CryptoSwift", package: "CryptoSwift"),
                .product(name: "SwiftyRSA", package: "SwiftyRSA"),
                .product(name: "JOSESwift", package: "JOSESwift"),
                .product(name: "SwiftJWT", package: "Swift-JWT"),
                .product(name: "SQLite", package: "SQLite.swift")
            ]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "ios-client-sdkTests",
            dependencies: ["ios-client-sdk"]),
    ]
)

If i try tu build with this command:
xcodebuild archive \
-scheme ios-client \
-destination "generic/platform=iOS" \
-archivePath ./output/clientsdk.xcarchive \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

I get some errors like this:
The following build commands failed:
    SwiftEmitModule normal arm64 Emitting\ module\ for\ Logging (in target 'Logging' from project 'swift-log')

SwiftEmitModule normal arm64 Emitting\ module\ for\ SQLite (in target 'SQLite' from project 'SQLite.swift')

SwiftEmitModule normal arm64 Emitting\ module\ for\ SwiftProtobuf (in target 'SwiftProtobuf' from project 'SwiftProtobuf')

SwiftDriver CryptorECC normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'CryptorECC' from project 'CryptorECC')

SwiftDriver CryptorRSA normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'CryptorRSA' from project 'CryptorRSA')

I've tried everything from clearing the cache to clearing the derivedData but nothing fix my problems.

The actual errors should be higher up in the output. You've just included the summary that says "something went wrong" without providing the part that went wrong.
